# How to get '{' in a formatted print statement in Python

Tags: python

In my Python program, I have:

```
jaar = 1949; maand = 9; dag = 23
print('{0:04d}-{1:02d}-{2:02d}  tekst '.format(jaar,maand,dag))
```

That works fine. However, I now need to include the text 'tekst' in
curly brackets {}. Even if I quote the brackets like in:

```
jaar = 1949; maand = 9; dag = 23
print('{0:04d}-{1:02d}-{2:02d}  \{tekst\} '.format(jaar,maand,dag))
```

this does not work, as Python seems to get confused about the two types of {}.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Because tekst in the print function doesn't have variable. Wrap tekst with double qualy braces {{tekst}}.

f-string approach is considered more readable and concise than the older .format() method.

```
print(f'{jaar:04d}-{maand:02d}-{dag:02d} {{tekst}}').
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It would be even better if you could edit it and format the code correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Use double curly brackets `{{` and `}}` around the text you want to enclose. In your case, the modified code would be:

```py
jaar = 1949; maand = 9; dag = 23
print('{0:04d}-{1:02d}-{2:02d}  {{tekst}} '.format(jaar, maand, dag))
```